# Youtube Data API UnknowPart Error When Create Broadcasting

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to create Youtube live stream through my webpage via Youtube Data API. Whatever I tried, keep getting that error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "'{0}'",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "'{0}'",
        "domain": "youtube.part",
        "reason": "unknownPart",
        "location": "part",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this error doesn't explain anything, and I couldn't find anything to help me to solve it. I hope someone can explain what is going on here.

I put all relative files down below and added some comments.

web.php

```
Route::get('youtube/{task}', [YoutubeController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('youtube.authenticate');
Route::get('youtube/{task}/redirect', [YoutubeController::class, 'create'])->name('youtube.create');
```

YoutubeController.php

```
class YoutubeController extends Controller
{
    private $youtube;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        // like YoutubeStreamService or YoutubeUploadService
        $this->youtube = new ("\App\Services\Youtube\Youtube" . ucfirst($request->route()->parameter('task')) . "Service");
    }

    public function authenticate($task)
    {
        return redirect()->away($this->youtube->authenticate($task));
    }

    public function create(Request $request, $task)
    {
        $this->youtube->create($request, $task);
    }
}
```

I use an abstract class for authentication codes.

```
abstract class YoutubeAbstraction
{
    // Called from the controller.
    // Returns the url to google to authenticate the request. 
    public function authenticate($task)
    {
        return $this->client($task)->createAuthUrl();
    }

    // This code came from mostly Youtueb API documentation.
    protected function client($task)
    {
        $scopes = [
            'upload' => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'],
            'stream' => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
        ][$task];
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("MyApp");
        $client->setScopes($scopes);
        $client->setAuthConfig(base_path("client_secret_{$task}.json"));
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        return $client;
    }

    abstract public function create($request, $task); 
}
```

YoutubeStreamService.php

```php
class YoutubeStreamService extends YoutubeAbstraction
{
    // This code came from Youtube API documentation completely.
    // It contains only the required fields and their hard-coded values.
    public function create($request, $task)
    {
        $client = $this->client($task);
        $client->setAccessToken($client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($request->code));

        $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);        
        $liveBroadcast = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();

        $liveBroadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
        $liveBroadcastSnippet->setTitle('my title');
        $liveBroadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime('2021-04-04T20:00:00.00+03:00');
        $liveBroadcast->setSnippet($liveBroadcastSnippet);

        $liveBroadcastStatus = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
        $liveBroadcastStatus->setPrivacyStatus('private');
        $liveBroadcast->setStatus($liveBroadcastStatus);

        // If I add dd($liveBroadcast) here, I see the object.
        // So the error is thrown by the function down below.

        $response = $service->liveBroadcasts->insert('', $liveBroadcast);
        print_r($response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the official specification, your call to the [`LiveBroadcasts.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) API endpoint has to include the request parameter:

> [**`part`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#part) (string)
>
> The `part` parameter serves two purposes in this operation. It identifies the properties that the write operation will set as well as the properties that the API response will include.
>
> The `part` properties that you can include in the parameter value are `id`, `snippet`, `contentDetails`, and `status`.

In PHP, that requirement boils down to having your API call like the one below:

```php
$response = $service->liveBroadcasts->insert(
    'id,snippet,status', $liveBroadcast);
```

Comment: Thanks stvar, I was almost going to be crazy.